# Incrementing a value a certain amount of times

Tags: c++, void

The user enters two times for their cellphone and computer. I am needing to set them equal to each other if they are different. Then I need to increment the computer time to 1 hour 5 minutes and 23 seconds faster than the cellphone clock.

This is my if statement.

```
   if (!myComputerClock.equalTime(cellPhoneClock))
    {
        myComputerClock=cellPhoneClock; 
        cout << "  The new time is: \n";
        cout << "  Cellphone: ";
        cellPhoneClock.printTime();
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "  Computer: ";
        myComputerClock.printTime();
    }
    else 
    {
        myComputerClock.incrementHours();
        myComputerClock.incrementMinutes();
        myComputerClock.incrementSeconds();
    }
```

Comment: `myComputerClock.setTime(chrs, cmins, csecs)=...` Looks odd...

Comment: What is the return time of `setTime`? I'm guessing - `void`!?

Comment: Rather than editing your question to change to a different question, please post a new question - that's how SO operates (it helps provide assistance to users in the future).

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which of the clocks you want to sync to, and then have two lines of code for each of the `setTime` calls. `setTime` is neither an lvalue or rvalue (meaning it neither accepts or returns a value), which is what the error is telling you.

Comment: Okay I got that part. Would you happen to know how I can increment the value of the computer clock to 1 hr 5 mis and 23 secs faster than the cellphone clock?

Comment: Depends on your platform and what API is available.